# GitHub Copilot not activation

Tags: github, github-copilot

GitHub Copilot show this error

> GitHub Copilot could not connect to server. Extension activation failed: "User not authorized"

But I have authorized on GitHub

[image: Unauthorized error]

Comment: Hey, I'm guessing you're not approved on the wait list.  You can check waitlist status on https://github.com/features/copilot/signup

Answer (score 11):

This is the scenario that happened to me.

1. I have multiple github accounts logged into my vscode.
2. In that only one account has access to the GitHub Copilot.

*So in order to give access to the token for the subscribed GitHub copilot, you should go to*

**1. Click the Accounts section at the bottom left side of the sidebar with a profile icon**

**2. Choose the GitHub profile you need to deactivate copilot.**

**3. Click Manage trusted extensions**

**4. Untick GitHub copilot/nightly.**

Comment: Thank you. Finally, this solution fixed my problem. It was connected to my Company's login and I'm paying on my personal one.

Comment: @tibasce It's great to hear that my solution helped you. I hope you have a great day!

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. Had to log out of my company account which was causing me this issue: `[auth] Invalid copilot token: missing token: 403 
... [error] [default] Extension activation failed: "Please contact your enterprise admin to enable your managed account for Copilot Business. You are currently logged in as ...` and then the extension asked me to log in, which I could do from my personal account.

Answer (score 5):

**Summary:**

If you are trying GitHub copilot for the **first time**, this error indicates that you are not part of the beta invite list. What you can do is you can **join the waitlist** (https://github.com/features/copilot/signup) and wait for your chance to try the beta.

If you have already got the invitation, then there was an error connecting to api.github.com to request a token to use the Copilot service.

**Full Discussion:** https://github.com/github/feedback/discussions/7707

**Update: Github Copilot is free until August 22, 2022**
(https://github.com/github-copilot/tp_signup)

Answer (score 5):

If you were previously using the Copilot limited invitation access,
as of June 23, mine got deactivated because Github Copilot will be free only until August 22.
I had to activate my free trial [here](https://github.com/github-copilot/tp_signup)

Comment: This was my case.

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue follow the below steps.

-First, go to your Github account.

-Go to setting select copilot and click on enable copilot.

-Then select Continue without payment details[image]

-Then allow and tick the check box.
-Now go to IDE and uninstall copilot and again install. then sign in to GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. In my case my card was expired, but they it didn't tell me that it was. Once I updated my card info it started working.

Answer (score 0):

If you already got the invitation:

1. Try signing out of your GitHub account from your IDE.
2. Disable and re-enable the `Copilot` extension.

Comment: "Try signing out of your GitHub account from your IDE"...great suggestion, but how?

Comment: @Fatedx In VSCode, in the bottom left corner, there is a user icon. Click on that and you'll see "github-username (GitHub)". If you hover it, there should be a "Sign Out" option.

Comment: In my case, I needed to re-sign in. Thanks - this led me to it.

Answer (score 0):

There is another open-source alternatives to it called CodeGeeX. The code is available at https://github.com/THUDM/CodeGeeX. Check out the VSCode extension at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=aminer.codegeex

Also, the model weights can be applied and download.

Comment: Is it possible to use this in a web browser (i.e. without downloading it)?